# SSH into EC2 by using a zsh script to fetch EC2 IP Address

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, zsh, ip-address

I'd like to create an alias in my zprofile that will fetch the EC2 IP address based on name tags, and then SSH into that machine. I'm using a mac.

This zsh script successfully retrieves the IP address of the EC2 machine I want to ssh into:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--filters "Name=tag:Name, Values=my-name" \
--query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress]" \
--output text
```

The output might look like: `some.ip.address`

This zsh script lets me SSH into my EC2 machine:

```
alias ec2="ssh person@some.ip.address.us-east-1.place"
```

How do I substitute the IP address of the second script with the output of my first script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to set up a second alias, so you could have something like:

```sh
alias get_ec2_ip='aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name, Values=my-name" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress]" --output text'
```

And then you could use zsh's [command substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html), like so:

```sh
alias ec2='ssh person@`get_ec2_ip`'
```

Note that it's super important to use single quotes there, not double quotes! Otherwise, you'll run `get_ec2_ip` when setting the alias, which is *not* what you want—you want it to save the literal string ssh person@`get_ec2_ip` as the alias, so that `get_ec2_ip` is run every time you run `ec2`.